# Managing Local Users Through Domain Policy

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, windows-xp, group-policy

How are people doing this where they work/play?  I am sick of dealing with registry hacks in the `NTUSER.DAT` file for the default user and erasing profiles for a guest account that is used for a lot of public kiosks.  I push out those changes through AD.  These computers are domain-joined, but a lot of politics has prevent the proper solution of a domain account for the kiosk guest user.  Does anyone handle this in a particularly clever way?

Answer (score 1):

If the kiosks are Windows xP and if you can find it I suggest using Steady State, you wont be able to find it on the Microsoft site as it has been discontinued.

The Windows Team blog has a write up on how to replicate most of the funtionality under Windows 7.

http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/springboard/archive/2010/09/27/steady-state-for-windows-7.aspx

Comment: This is why different departments abandoned Pharonics DeepFreeze. Post-deployments became impossible, and reliable methods became unstable. Essentially you have to create arbitrary maintenance windows for simple updates. Easy for servers, not easy for 24 hour students labs.  Haha.

Answer (score -1):

Only domain users (and domain computers) can be managed through a Group Policy. I would like to suggest too migrate those local users to domain users.

Comment: "These computers are domain-joined, but a lot of politics has prevent the proper solution of a domain account for the kiosk guest user." Next time, RTFOP.

Comment: An workaround would be to script it with delprof.exe and use that script in a Group Policy startup script.   You can target that Group Policy to the domain computer.